# Why is Instantiate only cloning four times?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

My issue here is that my object (a 500 long cube with a trigger on top) is only cloning four times with `Instantiate()`. Can anyone explain as to why? Is there a limit to how far you can clone items?

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class groundGen : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Transform player;
    public Object ground;
    public Transform groundLoc;

    public int distance = 500;

    public void OnTriggerEnter(Collider checkPass)
    {
        if (checkPass.tag == "checkpoint")
        {
            Instantiate(ground, groundLoc.position + new Vector3(0, 0, distance), groundLoc.rotation);
            distance += 500;
        }
    }
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
     
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no real limit.

But:

1. there is some inaccuracy due to floating point numbers, if your coordinates get really big.
2. Your meshes could get clipped by Camera. Log your Instantiate Calls and check hierarchy in Playmode. Increase Cameras far-plane if needed.

Comment: I know my camera isn't clipping, so how would I go about handling large integers?

Comment: Don't worry about  that, 4x 500 is wayyy to small to impact that. We are talking about the limits of a float.

Comment: Does... every cloned object have that script as well? Are you instantiating exponentially? 2, 4, 8 ,16 ... ? But even that should not stop at 4...

Comment: Is the "ground" deleted maybe? Your code sounds like an infinite runner game. Maybe after 4, the "original" is offscreen and gets deleted by another script of yours? Then, instantiate may fail.

Comment: Ah. I only have a six digit float. Could that be the issue?

Comment: No, I have not implemented removal yet.

Comment: No, only the original `ground` has the script.

Comment: Ok, but if you continue walking, how does the other (instantiated) objects trigger your OnTriggerEnter? The problem is most likely not the Instantiate itself, but your function not being called. Add a Debug.Log() to see if it's called.

Comment: The original all passed the debug, but for some reason the fourth clone does not.

Comment: You should check if it has a collider. It can help to use the [Window->Analysis->Physics Debugger](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/PhysicsDebugVisualization.html) (be sure to have gizmos enabled). Also check the layer and the tag.

Comment: No dice. Thanks for your help, I think I'll just keep tinkering with it until something (hopefully) happens. :)

Comment: did you solve it? Otherwise, make a screenshot of your setup, the objects, where a script is attached etc. - maybe I have an Idea. Right now, I cannot reproduce it, only using your script.

Comment: I wouldn't say I solved it, but I do believe it might be a rendering issue where unity can't reach the `ground` base. I ended up just rewriting the code. Thanks for the help though :)